# Stopwords coming up in most influential words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I am running some NLP code, trying to find the most influential (positively or negatively) words in a survey. My problem is that, while I successfully add some extra stopwords to the NLTK stopwords file, they keep coming up as influential words later on.

So, I have a dataframe, first column contains scores, second column contains comments.

I add extra stopwords:

```
stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
extra = ['Cat', 'Dog']
stopwords.extend(extra)
```

I check that they are added, using the len method before and after.

I create this function to remove punctuation and stopwords from my comments:

```
def text_process(comment):
   nopunc = [char for char in comment if char not in string.punctuation]
   nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
   return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in stopwords]
```

I run the model (not going to include the whole code since it doesn't make a difference):

```
corpus = df['Comment']
y = df['Label']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer=text_process)
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

...

And then to get the most influential words:

```
feature_to_coef = {word: coef for word, coef in zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), nb.coef_[0])}


for best_positive in sorted(
    feature_to_coef.items(), 
    key=lambda x: x[1], 
    reverse=True)[:20]:
    print (best_positive)
```

But, Cat and Dog are in the results.

What am I doing wrong, any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is because you have capitalize words 'Cat' and 'Dog'

In your text_process function, you have `if word.lower() not in stopwords` which only works if the stopwords are lower case